# Determine current AWS region .Net?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

Is there a way to determine the current AWS region in .Net?

I've been able to find a way to do this in java https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/determining-an-applications-current-region/ but cannot find the equivalent in .Net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the .NET SDK, it's as simple as

```
var region = Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.Region;
```

It has two main properties, `DisplayName` and `SystemName`.  The former gives you strings such as `"EU West (London)"`, while the latter gives `"eu-west-2"`.

Comment: Strangely I am getting TaskCancelled exception on this line of code.
   at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.get_Region() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+coreclr\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line 214

Comment: @Signcodeindie That would suggest that you're calling it in a place where your outer thread/request/whatever is completing before it can get hold of it - internally it's doing a webrequest to get hold of the data (unless it's already cached it), so it's not an instant thing.  Depending what's going on, may be worth a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This information is available on an EC2 instance from the EC2 Metadata Service. Actually, only the Availability Zone is available but you can infer the region from the AZ.

It looks like this is available in the .Net SDK via [Amazon.EC2.Util](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/NEC2Util.html) and [EC2Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2UtilEC2Metadata.html).